# electron certificates network

Tags: ssl, electron

I am trying to write a simple electron app to interface with a REST server.  The server doesn't have the appropriate certificates.  When I try to make a 'GET' request (using fetch()), I get the following error message:

```
  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT
```

Fixing the certs is not currently an option.  I tried to use the 'ignore-certificates-error' flag (see below). It seems like it should allow me to skip over this error, but it doesn't.

```
var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');
...
```

The result is the same error.

Questions:

- I am correct in assuming this options is supposed to help here?
- If so, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Electron version: 1.2.8

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using client certificates?

Comment: The REST server requires using HTTPS. I am assuming what's causing this. If I am wrong, let me know.

Comment: HTTPS only requires a server certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your version of electron and use this callback:

```
app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, link, error, certificate, callback) => {
  if ('yourURL/api/'.indexOf(link) !== -1) {
    // Verification logic.
    event.preventDefault();
    callback(true);
  } else {
    callback(false);
  }
});
```

That you going do the fetch to your api with https.